# What do you call a sentence with only one word?

Tags: single-word-requests

If someone answers "Yes, I am." to some question of mine, I might say that she gave a monosyllabic answer.

If someone answers simply "Yes." and I want to emphasize that her answer consists of only one word, would I say that she gave a *monoword* answer? Or something else?

Comment: What I'm saying is that the answer has already been given there. If you like, pretend the close vote is for 'easily answerable by using generally available resources' (that thread); I thought I'd use the 'duplicate' option so that the hyperlink would automatically appear here. A one-word sentence with no verb is an impossibility from the way a sentence is defined: A grammatical unit that is syntactically independent and has a subject that is expressed or, as in imperative sentences, understood and a predicate that contains at least one finite verb. [AHD]

Comment: The usual terminology for  non-sentences that are often used and make sense (Hello!, No thanks, On the table, Yes) is 'sentence substitutes'.

Comment: I'm not interested in debating whether or not such sentences are "possible" or "correct" or "grammatical". Clearly. They. Are. Possible. I just want to know what one might call such a sentence.

Comment: A string of (1 or more) words with a capital letter at the front and a full stop at the end is not defined as a sentence. For instance, 'Yes.' (I've put in the full stop to show the exact quote with associated punctuation) is **not a sentence** but a sentence substitute. There's nothing wrong with using it (correctly), just with calling it a 'sentence'. **sentence substitute**
n
(Linguistics) a word or phrase, esp one traditionally classified as an adverb, that is used in place of a finite sentence, such as _yes_ , _no_ , _certainly_ , and _never_ . [Collins]

Comment: I frankly don't understand the question. If you're prepared to label an utterance of three syllables (_Yes I am_) as "monosyllabic", you might have to go into negative numbers to describe _Yes_.

Comment: Aren't one-word instructions like "Relax." and "Go!" complete sentences? They have an implied subject, but then so does "Don't take my word for it."

Comment: @Sven Yargs You could certainly argue that an implied subject in an imperative statement confers 'sentencehood' on the construction. However, OP muddies the waters: 'If someone answers simply "Yes." ...' This is certainly not a sentence by almost all definitions. Using the term 'minor sentence' for such strings really messes things up, as a minor sentence then is not a sentence.

Comment: Why would we have a tag "single-word requests" if there was better term for that?

Comment: I suspect that “monosyllabic” was meant to indicate that “Yes I am” comprises only monosyllabic words. It's a bit of an odd usage, true. Anyway, I'm voting to reopen because the “duplicate” question does not answer this question at all.

Comment: Sesquipedalian.  (And you gotta have the period or you don't meet the 15-character minimum.)

Answer (score 4):

In ‘The Cambridge Encyclopedia of the English Language’, David Crystal recognises a **minor sentence** as one ‘where there is limited productivity, or where the structure lacks some of the constituents to be found in the major type.’ He gives as an example *No way*. The description would seem to apply to sentences that have only one word.

Comment: A 'minor sentence' is characterized by the absence of a verb, not the number of words.

Answer (score 0):

The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_word) on the topic calls these kinds this a *sentence word* or *word sentence*, but also gives such terms as *volzinwoorden* and *Wortsätze*.

It also discusses the use of such words among children, and refers these words as **holophrases**:

> single-word utterance which is used by a child to express more than one meaning usually attributed to that single word by adults

More info found in the article on [*holophrasis*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holophrasis).

Comment: Wikipedia mentions 'word sentences,' though I think that's more of an academic term. The link under that term contradicts, in a way, the very sentence from where it is drawn!

Answer (score -2):

One should consider this a general reference question. However:

Why would we have a tag "single-word requests" if there was a better term for that? Technically, there's no such thing as a *monoword*, though *polyword* is well known, mostly as an adjective.

If you chose to be **informal**:

> 1. *[monoword](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=monoword)*. Being of few words, being quite cold in the reply.

Wikipedia mentions *[word sentence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_%28linguistics%29#Major_and_minor_sentences)s*, though I think that's more of an academic term. (The link under that term contradicts, in a way, the very sentence from where it is drawn!)

---

*sentence*:

> a set of words that is complete in itself, typically containing a subject and predicate, conveying a statement, question, exclamation, or command, and consisting of a main clause and sometimes one or more subordinate clauses.

A "set" can consist of any number of words, including one, or even none.

Further to that, everything else is qualified with "typical" but not necessarily.

"Yes." is a *sentence*. QED.

By the way, "Yes, I am." is not monosyllabic.